# Waiting to load URL to return data AS3

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, url, event-handling

I have a function which has data which is in a for loop, the data is passed into my function, the function puts the data into a URL loader, loads it, and returns the data from the loaded URL. This doesn't work as if I try doing it with no stops the URL is not loaded quick enough to return the data. I can't find a way to put stops in so it doesn't cause errors. I can't use an event listener because they can't return values and I can't just make a function to assign the data to a variable because it is needed in the function which called the function with the URLloader. I can make a diagram to explain better. I am not too sure if this will be possible of if somehow I need to restructure my code. I have tried these two ways:
This causes a stack overflow:

```
package app
{
    import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        var geoReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest;
        var geoLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var GeocodeResponse:XML;
        var geoLocList:XMLList = new XMLList();
        var geoLoc:Array = new Array();
        function main():void
        {
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=flu&rpp=3&lang=en&geocode=55.378051,-3.435973,605mi");
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getTweets);
            loader.load(urlReq);
        }
        function getTweets( e:Event ):void
        {
            if ( e.target.data )
            {
                var tweets = new Array(); var times = new Array();
                var twitterXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
                var tweetList:XMLList = twitterXML.children();
                var tweetItem:String;
                var placeItem:String;
                var tweet:Array = new Array();
                for (var i:int = 0; i < tweetList.length(); i++)
                {
                    tweetItem = tweetList[i].*::title;
                    placeItem = tweetList[i].*::location;
                    if( tweetItem && placeItem != "")
                    {
                    placeItem = loadGeo(placeItem);
                    tweet = [tweetItem, placeItem];
                    tweets.push(tweet);
                    trace(tweets[tweets.length - 1][0]);
                    trace(tweets[tweets.length - 1][1]);
                    }
                }
                trace(tweets.length);
            }
        }
        function loadGeo(loc:String):Array
        {
            geoReq = new URLRequest("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+loc+"&sensor=false");
            geoLoader.load(geoReq);
            GeocodeResponse = new XML(geoLoader.data);
            geoLoc = returnLoc();
            return geoLoc;
        }
        function returnLoc():Array
        {
            if(geoLoader.data == null)
            {
                returnLoc();
            }
            else
            {
                var returnD:Array = new Array(GeocodeResponse.result.geometry.location[0].lat, GeocodeResponse.result.geometry.location[0].lng);
            }
            return returnD;
        }
    }
}
```

And this causes the error "TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.":

```
package app
{
    import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        var geoReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest;
        var geoLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var GeocodeResponse:XML;
        var geoLocList:XMLList = new XMLList();
        var geoLoc:Array = new Array();
        function main():void
        {
            var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=flu&rpp=3&lang=en&geocode=55.378051,-3.435973,605mi");
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getTweets);
            loader.load(urlReq);
        }
        function getTweets( e:Event ):void
        {
            if ( e.target.data )
            {
                var tweets = new Array(); var times = new Array();
                var twitterXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
                var tweetList:XMLList = twitterXML.children();
                var tweetItem:String;
                var placeItem:String;
                var tweet:Array = new Array();
                for (var i:int = 0; i < tweetList.length(); i++)
                {
                    tweetItem = tweetList[i].*::title;
                    placeItem = tweetList[i].*::location;
                    if( tweetItem && placeItem != "")
                    {
                    placeItem = loadGeo(placeItem);
                    tweet = [tweetItem, placeItem];
                    tweets.push(tweet);
                    trace(tweets[tweets.length - 1][0]);
                    trace(tweets[tweets.length - 1][1]);
                    }
                }
                trace(tweets.length);
            }
        }
        function loadGeo(loc:String):Array
        {
            geoReq = new URLRequest("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+loc+"&sensor=false");
            geoLoader.load(geoReq);
            GeocodeResponse = new XML(geoLoader.data);
            geoLoc = [GeocodeResponse.result.geometry.location[0].lat, GeocodeResponse.result.geometry.location[0].lng];
            return geoLoc;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, thanks in advance, Kyle.

Answer (score 1):

You are waiting for completion of `search.twitter.com` request, but you do not wait for completion of geocode request. This is the error. Every time you use a Loader, you employ asynchronous waiting.

Comment: Is there anyway I can employ synchronous waiting so that I can use the data returned from geoLoader() to put into the tweet[] array?

Comment: Sure, but you have to move the code following `geoloader.load()` into `Event.COMPLETE` event handler. Note that since you are now requesting multiple geocodes, you have to devise a functionality to determine which geocode loader dispatched "complete" event, and add correct geocode data to twitters by parsing the result.

Comment: I have done that but like my other code I realise that the data has not been retrieved from the google api url before I try to assign it to a var, therefore it outputs null :/